# Make lazy loading faster and responsive in iOS App

Tags: objective-c, json, uitableview, lazy-loading, nsoperationqueue

In my iOS app I've a class that performs a web request to get an array of informations located in mySQL DB. In this class I've a method that do this taking as input a mySQL query:

```
- (NSMutableArray *) myreq:(NSString *)query{

    // Create NSData object
    NSData *dataQuery = [query
                         dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // Get NSString from NSData object in Base64
    NSString *base64EncodedQuery = [dataQuery base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

    // Print the Base64 encoded string
    NSLog(@"Encoded: %@", base64EncodedQuery);

    NSMutableString *strURL = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"http://…=%@“,base64EncodedQuery];

    [strURL setString:[strURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    

    NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

    NSError* error;

    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:dataURL
                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];

    NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    int numRow = 0;

    for (NSArray *arrow in json) {
        [results addObjectsFromArray:arrow];
        numRow++;
    }   
    return results;
}
```

This method send a query to a php script that perform immediately this query to MySQL DB and get a json with results. I translate the json in this method and finally return an array with results.
I call myreq in a method

```
- (void)downloadScope{

    _arrID = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _arrIDUsers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _arrUsernames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _arrPictures = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   [myQueue addOperation:[NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock: ^{

        query = @"SELECT ID FROM mytable”;
        [_arrID addObjectsFromArray:[self myreq:query]];

        for (int i = 0; i < [_arrID count]; i++) {

                NSArray *tempArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self myreq:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT IDUsr,usrn, pictureaddress FROM mytable WHERE ID = %@",_arrID[i]]]];

    [_arrIDUsers insertObject:tempArray[0] atIndex:i];
    [_arrUsernames insertObject:tempArray[2] atIndex:i];
    [_arrPictures insertObject:tempArray[2] atIndex:i];

            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                    [self.tableView reloadData];

                }];
            }
            }]];

    [myQueue setSuspended:NO];
}
```

In tableView I create cells in this way (using SDWebImage):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Identificatore di cella
    NSString *identifier = @“cellmy”;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    cell.backgroundColor = nil;

    if ( cell == nil ) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }

    NSString *username = [self.arrUsernames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    UILabel *cellLabelUsername = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    cellLabelUsername.text = [username uppercaseString];

UIImageView *cellImageProfileSnap = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:5];

    [cellImageProfileSnap sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[_arrPictures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@“…”]];
}
```

In viewDidLoad I initialize my NSOperationQueue (defined in my interface):

```
myQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [myQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:100];
    [myQueue setName:@"com.sada"];
```

My goal is to make everything faster because the loading in tableView is slow and I think that is not dependent on SDWebImage. Please help me

Comment: Please define your problem clearly e.g. how slow it is or where do you think it's slow or how is the user experience right now.

Comment: There is something I wrong in code I wrote?

Comment: I'd like to have after loading for example 100 cells populate each with its own username, and the download of picture by sdwenimage play when cell is shown

Comment: The loading is too slow in 3G connection, instead in WiFi connection is enought speed.

Comment: I've the same problem, but it seems nobody know how to help us

Comment: You won't get the answer here if you are not specific. This is not a guessing game. One problem I see here is that you never stop loading image after the cell has been recycled. You better use `tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` of `UITableViewDelegate` to stop loading image after the cell has been removed.